# Placement of "for all" in "show that"

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

In a mathematical text, suppose that we have a statement *A(n)* where *n* is a number. My question is where the phrase "for all *n*" should stand in "show that":

- For all *n*[,] show that *A(n)* holds.
- Show[,] for all *n*[,] that *A(n)* holds.
- Show that[,] for all *n*[,] the statement *A(n)* holds.
- Show that *A(n)* holds[,] for all *n*.

About the commas, I feel like they are necessary in the first and third sentence, yet the phrase "for all *n*" is, in my opinion, quite important for the understanding of the whole sentence (e.g. should *A(n)* only holds for one *n* or no *n*?). Moreover, is it safe to leave out the first comma in the third statement?

Comment: Show that A(*n*) holds for all *n*.

Comment: Can you narrow this down to a single question? It seems to me that you have several here.

Comment: You are asking for an English opinion about a standard, preformatted phrasing in math. By convention: "For all n, show that A(n) holds." Don't hafta be good English if it's specialized wording in another field.

Comment: First one is good, while the accepted version is math text must be "Show that [] holds for all $n$".

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the commas: I would agree that "for all *n*" is central to the meaning of the sentence, so it is not parenthetical and cannot be set apart completely. The only comma that makes sense is the one following the prepositional phrase (and even this is not strictly necessary since the phrase is short). Any other commas surrounding the phrase indicate that it is non-essential, when in reality the question's objective relies on it. Thus:

- For all *n*, show that *A(n)* holds.
- Show for all *n* that *A(n)* holds.
- Show that for all *n*(,) the statement *A(n)* holds. (A comma can be placed after the phrase here, but to me the sentence flows better without it. No comma should be used before it.)
- Show that *A(n)* holds for all *n*.

Overall, I think the last option is the most straightforward in conveying the task at hand. They all roughly indicate the same thing . . . but if there is a semantic argument to be made, one could construe the first and second as asking the reader (solver?) to show that *A(n)* holds individually for every possible *n*, implying a laborious case-by-case proof, while the third and fourth make it clear that the task is simply to show generally that *A(n)* always holds.